# phpBB3 allow a link on forum image

Tags: phpbb3

When creating a new forum, an option is

```
Forum image:
Location, relative to the phpBB root directory, of an additional image to associate with this forum.
```

Is there a way to add to make the image a live link?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do it :

- Option 1: You can define U_SITE_HOME in your admin panel to your external URL . But, when he clicks on the first link in Breadcrumbs, he will be redirect to this external link too.
- Option 2 : If you only want an live link for the logo and if it is only for your forum, you can alter [overall_header.html file](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/master/phpBB/styles/prosilver/template/overall_header.html) in line 83 to :

  `<a id="logo" class="logo" href="http://www.example.org" title="Example site "><span class="site_logo"></span></a>`

Comment: Yes it is only for my forum. I don't mind an absolute link at all. It just has to allow a person clicking on the button to go to an external site given by that link.

Comment: I will look at that file. Thanks